# How to set JMS_IBM_MQMD_ACCOUNTINGTOKEN in JMSMessage

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

After processing a message I need to set the Accounting Token on the msg. How do I set it in the outbound message. I have tried the following and it does not work

```
msg.setObjectProperty(JmsConstants.JMS_IBM_MQMD_ACCOUNTINGTOKEN,value)
```

where value set is a byte[]. But when I observe the message the AccountingToken is not getting set.

Is there something I am missing over here?

Comment: What about the answer below? Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further analysis I found that the reason why it was not getting set was because the following property was not set.

```
((JmsDestination) dest).setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_WRITE_ENABLED, true);
```

After setting the above value the accounting token was available.

Answer (score 0):

From [IBM Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/jm41050_.htm?cp=SSFKSJ_7.0.1/1-25-3-4-10-0-1&lang=en):

> For certain properties, you must also set the WMQ_MQMD_MESSAGE_CONTEXT
>   property on the Destination object. (...)
>   The following properties require WMQ_MQMD_MESSAGE_CONTEXT to be set to
>   WMQ_MDCTX_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT or WMQ_MDCTX_SET_ALL_CONTEXT:
>
> ```
> JMS_IBM_MQMD_UserIdentifier
> JMS_IBM_MQMD_AccountingToken
> JMS_IBM_MQMD_ApplIdentityData
> ```